# PDFBox, iTextPdfPDF: pdf form returning no fields

Tags: itext, pdfbox, xfa

I have a pdf file which has several form fields which can be filled with values, like text fields, radio box etc.

I am trying to manipulate the fields programmatically by reading the pdf. I have tried libraries like PDFBox, iTextPdf etc. But every time I see fields list returned empty. My basic code is:

```
val template = new File(....)
val doc = PDDocument.load(template)
val docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog
val acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm
println("Fields:"+ acroForm.getFields)
```

Fields list is coming out to be empty, even though file does have fields.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your PDF have _interactive_ fields or just things that look like fields? And if they are interactive, is the form definition XFA or is it AcroForm?

Comment: I can interact with those fields. But I am not sure of XFA vs Acroform. Any easy way to check that?

Comment: I think its XFA. When I inspect itextpdf PdfReader object, I see an attribute in it named XFA, and its non-null.

Comment: *"But I am not sure of XFA vs Acroform. Any easy way to check that?"* - call `acroForm.hasXFA()`.

Comment: yup, hasXFA is true.

Comment: Ok, so I need to convert it to acroform then. Thanks for inputs.

Comment: Ok, pure XFA forms are not supported by many PDF libraries, in particular because it essentially is not related to PDF mechanisms at all, it's a pure XML form definition. The PDF specifications deprecated XFA in PDF in 2017.

Comment: @Mandroid Can you write this an an answer? This would help others to quickly spot the solution...

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the input pdf file I was using is actually a XFA based file and not acroform, and most of the libraries don't support XFA.

So we need to convert the file to acroform.

Another approach can be to use [aspose](https://github.com/aspose-pdf). It provides API to populate XFA forms too.